# `mix ecto.create` throwing weird localhost:5432 connection error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, elixir-mix

This is my first time using Elixir + Phoenix. I am simply attempting to run mix ecto.create and I am getting the follow error:

```
    19:08:28.529 [error] GenServer #PID<0.295.0> terminating
** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:84: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
    (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Last message: nil
State: Postgrex.Protocol
** (Mix) The database for DwayneFM.Repo couldn't be created: killed
```

Any idea what could be causing it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused`. You were unable to connect to your database. Do you have postgres running? Are your credentials correct? Do you have an issue with your `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: @JustinWood Thank you. I ran into the same issue and didn't realize PostgreSQL wasn't running. Once it was it solved the issue I was having.